# How do I return unique rows from two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison

I have two student tables in SQL Server, a base table from my original run and the new table from the next days run. Each table has info like Building, UserID LastName FirstName:

**Base** table:

```
3   2509381 Brooks  Corey   
3   2527352 Doss    Dawone  
14  170163  Belin   Teaira  
14  2465666 Arlington   Xavier  
14  2465941 Smith   Jerald  
14  2466022 Junious Dontrell    
14  2466898 Shelton Rayonna 
14  2468144 Sullivan    James   
14  2468612 Brown   Jerron  
14  2469949 Quinn   Jordan
```

New table:

```
3   2527352 Doss    Dawone  
14  170163  Belin   Teaira  
14  2465666 Arlington   Xavier  
14  2465941 Smith   Jerald  
14  2466022 Junious Dontrell    
14  2466898 Shelton Rayonna 
14  2468144 Sullivan    James   
14  2468612 Brown   Jerron  
3   2469949 Quinn   Jordan  
14  1234512 Davis   John
```

In my example here, Brooks was deleted, Quinn had building number changed, and Davis was added I'd like my result table to look something like this.

**Audit** table:

```
3   2509381 Brooks  Corey   
14  2469949 Quinn   Jordan  
14  1234512 Davis   John
```

I am using two except queries, to get these results

select *
from test1
except
select *
from test2

```
3   2509381 Brooks  Corey   
14  2469949 Quinn   Jordan
```

select *
from test2
except
select *
from test1

```
3   2469949 Quinn   Jordan  
14  1234512 Davis   John
```

How do I get them to output all the deltas in the audit table.  I tried to Union my two select statements but that didn't work...

Comment: Why is your result set ignoring the `Building = 3` row from the first table?

Comment: I believe you may have to Google on JOINs in SQL and try something first.  Your question shows no effort you put on making the query.

Comment: that audit table misses some information what happend ( like 'insert', 'update','delete')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the student numbers are unique? Or there is some way to determine what is a unique row if you haven't provided all columns. You need this, otherwise you cannot detect what is new and what is changed. Or what is deleted and added.

Typically we would use a query that joins items together on a unique field, which could be UserID in this case. Your join would then need to compare the various other fields.

An outer join will tell if you something about inserts and deletes. For example, I could do this:

```
select *
 from base b
   full outer join new n
   on b.userid = n.userid
```

If you do this, then you'll see various things. If there are NULLs for the b.userid but not n.userid, then you have new rows in the New table that don't exist in the base table. If you have the reverse, then you have had a delete. For changes, you could compare values of each column and then determine what's different. You might choose to handle this in a few queries that each look for separate things, like an insert query, a delete query, and a change query. You can UNION those together for a result hat you can insert into an audit table.

Note: In many systems, we would use a trigger to capture these changes in real time for auditing (or another auditing mechanism in SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to build an exception query, and use an insert into a new table to capture the data:

Create table mytable_audit
    (Building, UserID, Lastname, Firstname, Audit_Date)

```
Insert into mytable_audit
Select Building, UserID, Lastname, Firstname, getdate() from mytable2
EXCEPT 
Select Building, UserID, Lastname, Firstname, getdate() from mytable
```

The only problem with that approach is it won't tell you *why* the data is in the table. You can get around this by making this a subquery (provided as wayOutwest said that you have a unique key) and then join back on to the source table. That way you can add a case statement to provide an indicator.
Finally a UNION to a second query checks for deleted students:

```
Create table mytable_audit
    (Building int, Username int, Lastname varchar(100), Firstname varchar(100), Audit_Date datetime, ChangeType varchar(100))

    Insert into mytable_audit

    Select aa.*, getdate(),
    case when aa.building<>mt.building then 'Building Changed'
         when mt.userid is null then 'Student Added'
         when aa.lastname<>mt.lastname or aa.firstname<>mt.firstname then 'Student Name Changed'
    end as changetype
    from 
    (Select Building, UserID, Lastname, Firstname from mytable2
    EXCEPT 
    Select Building, UserID, Lastname, Firstname from mytable) aa

    left join mytable mt on aa.userID=mt.userID

    UNION 

    Select Building, UserID, Lastname, Firstname, getdate(), 'Student Removed' from mytable mt
    left join mytable2 mt2 on mt.userid=mt2.userid
    where mt2.userid is null
```